# PHP - finding a link in a variable that contains something

Tags: php, parsing, variables

In php how would I find a custom link that I wouldn't fully know?

What I need to know is how to find a custom link in a variable.  I won't know exactly what the link is, but I will know that it'll be like `http://example.com/search/results/<randomnumber>`.  The link I want displayed in the last sentence will be the first link of it's kind.  So I think I would need to get the first link in the variable that contains `http://example.com/search/results/`.

So to simplify things if I have a variable with 1000 links in it how would I find the first link that contains `http://example.com/search/results/`, and print it?

Comment: use a regex with preg_match()

Comment: by "link" do you mean urls? Or actual links like `<a href='http://www....'>`?

Comment: I would want to obtain the value of href in an a tag.

Comment: To parse HTML, just use [dom document](http://www.php.net/domdocument). load the html string, getElementsByTagName('a') and then get the href attribute. Check it and get your url/id.

Answer (score -2):

You could create an array from the string by using [explode()](https://www.php.net/explode) on the string.

You would then need to loop through all of the links and check if it matches.

```
foreach ($link as $l) {
   if (preg_match('/http:\/\/example.com\/search\/results\//', $l, $matches) {
       // Do something with link
       break; // break out of loop since we found first one
   }
}
```

Comment: I believe OP has a string, not an array.

Comment: What if the links are within a bunch of text? what would you explode on?

Comment: OP just said a variable with 1000 links, I'm not going to account for every possibility.

Comment: OP says contains not equals.

Comment: OP also says links, not urls. So the likely result would be a string of html links.